# Open folder's files through main index in php

Tags: php

this is my main public_html index code
[image]

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Write you own problem description _in text form_ here, please, do not show _images_ of text or code.

Comment: What error you are getting? 404 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only index.php file in your public_html folder how it should go to the theme folder post.php file?

a) You need to clone index.php file, change its name to post.php and change its content to point to post file.
b) You can also use .httaccess mod rewrite to redirect
c) You can also build a switching function withing main index.php file like this:

```
...
$goto = 'index.php';
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
  if ($_GET['action'] == 'post') $goto = 'post.php';
  //elseif for more options...
}
require(dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'themes/'.$goto);
...
```

Usage: "index.php?action=post" would load post.php in themes, while "index.php" will load default index.php in themes...

Maybe the best solution would be to add action switching to index.php and mod rewrite to .htaccess if necessary eg.

```
RewriteRule ^post\.html ./index.php?action=post [R=301,L]
```

Hope I helped a bit.

Comment: if more then 2 files in theme folder then??

Comment: You can make more "if" statements to switch files or build generic rewrite rules. It all depends what you actually want to do...

Your problem is you are trying to open file that does not exists in the public_html folder. Your index.php file or server will not do any magic for you. Your need to fix your links or tell the server how to redirect requests.